# How to grant read access to all files in a folder and subfolders using c#?

Tags: c#

How to grant read access to all files in a folder and subfolders in windows 7 using c#?

I do not own some files but I have administrative privileges.

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Comment: Looks like a combination of [granting permission to all users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540161/how-do-i-programatically-change-the-security-attributes-of-a-file-so-that-any-us) and [granting permission recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289950/recursive-security-settings)

Answer (score 2):

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\yourDir");
DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = dirInfo.GetAccessControl();

dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule
    (Enviroment.Username,
    FileSystemRights.ReadData, AccessControlType.Allow));

dirInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSecurity);
```

Comment: I think the question is about NTFS permissions, not .net permissions.

Comment: @CodeInChaos thanks for the correction, I have modified accordingly.

Comment: @Shark I am having unauthorized exception on GetAccessControl. I do not own the file. but I can go from file's property window and take ownership. no idea why I cannot do from c#