# How to Set File Access Permission for Scanning All Files in C#

Tags: c#, .net, security, c#-4.0

I am Trying to write a  Functionality where i could get the Complete List of All File Name in all Drives,but I am stuck in a place where its giving me security exception to read all files.
I went through many of the articles in this site and the other, but unable to figure out how to set complete access rights

this post was much useful but i am getting an Exception which was unanswered in that thread

[How to grant read access to all files in a folder and subfolders using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8278822/how-to-grant-read-access-to-all-files-in-a-folder-and-subfolders-using-c?answertab=active#tab-top)

Now My code looks like this

```
 [FileIOPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Read = "C:\\")]
public void GetAllFilesFromPhysicalDrives()
{
List<DriveInfo> allphydrives = GetListofPhysicalDrivesOnly(); //Gets All Physical DrivesCollection              
try
{
foreach (DriveInfo dr in allphydrives)
{
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dr.Name); 
DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = dir.GetAccessControl();
dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Environment.UserName, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Allow));
dir.SetAccessControl(dirSecurity);
FileSystemAccessRule faRule;    
FileSystemRights fsrRights;
DirectorySecurity dirsec;
fsrRights = FileSystemRights.FullControl;
faRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(new  System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("my-pc\\me"),fsrRights,InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow);
System.Security.Principal.NTAccount account = new  System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("me\\me");
dirsec = Directory.GetAccessControl("C:\\");
dirsec.SetOwner(account);
dirsec.AddAccessRule(faRule);
Directory.SetAccessControl("C:\\", dirsec);
}
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
}
```

so when the code to set the access executes i am getting an **"Attempt to Perform UnAuthorized Operation"** Exception

I don't want to set Permission for files one by one because its a tedious task so help me which would happen dynamically via code for All folders so that i could iterate and get all file names .(I don't intend to get windows related files or kernal files ,just the user created files is enough)

Comment: **Don't do that**. Your code creates an enormous security hole.

Comment: so is there any way to get this done in the right way? , i am just trying to implement few basic functionality here

Comment: You run the app from an account with permision to see all files. Work on the basis that the app will scan all files applicable to the user running it.

Comment: To get _what_ done the right way?

Comment: Currently i tried to debug this code with a admin user id ,also i have tried to run the exe run as admin -but still the issue was persisting

Comment: "To get what done the right way? – SLaks " - How to do without having any security exception?

Comment: Another Logic Just Struck ME- What if i Skip the Folders which are Sensitive /Need Exclusive rights like C:\Windows folder , and then iterate to get the other files

Comment: Yes; that will work much better.

Comment: To debug it, you'd have to run VS as an admin.